# django url config - inconsistent local vs. EC2 hosted

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a Django 2.2 application running Python 3.8.10. Trying to research and debug a confusing issue related to urls.

Essentially we have `/org` urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include("project.urls")),
    url(r'^$', views.frontpage, name="frontpage"),
    url(r'^org/submit/$', views.org_create_new, name="org-create-new"),
    url(r'^org/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', views.org),

    # redirect traffic that doesn't match a url to root home
    url(r'^.*$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('frontpage')), name='home'),
]
```

and `project` urls

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^manage/', include('management.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('users.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('common.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('products.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This configuration works fine locally with no issues. However, when we deploy the application (to AWS EC2) the `org.urls` and `management.urls` don't work, but the remaining urls do. Django admin can be accessed, `common.urls` and `users.urls` serve fine, but a GET request to "frontpage" view for example simply returns `404 Not Found`. There's no error message. If I turn on DEBUG=True for the EC2 version of the app it will simply say:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    https://927-app-url-test.z207817de.gdb.sh/
Raised by:  orgs.views.all.frontpage
```

if I sh into the EC2 instance and run `python manage.py show_urls` I see all the urls, including the ones that are returning 404 Not Found:

```
/   orgs.views.all.frontpage    frontpage
/.* django.views.generic.base.RedirectView  home
```

If I go into python shell of the server-hosted application, I can also reverse the missing urls:

```
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.urls import reverse
>>> reverse('frontpage')
'/'
>>> reverse('admin-dashboard')
'/manage/dashboard/'
```

Why are these urls not discoverable when a request is made? Is there an error in our urls config? Any recommendations on how to debug further? thanks